# How to best determine queries involved in a deadlock on postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I am working on GCP CloudSQL postgres v12.11 and see a few deadlocks in the postgres log.  However, there is not any query information.  Looking through the postgres documentation, there does seem to many options to identify the queries.  Turning on logging for all queries really is not an option. Any advice on how to identify the queries in a deadlock on postgres would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you see in the logs?  What are your log settings?

Comment: All I see is the "ERROR: deadlock detected" log entry and the next log entry is "ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block".  I really do not see any statements involved in the deadlock.  This is on GCP Cloudsql Postgres.  No special logging flags have been turned on yet - default settings.

Comment: Let me know which postgres flags to investigate further for deadlocks.  Thx!

Comment: I was only searching for Errors hence only a couple of audit rows came back.  When I looked at the all audit entries, I saw the Details - LOG, CONTEXT, DETAIL, ...etc. the other lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries happening during the deadlock are logged anyway, unless you disable error logging. There is no other place where you can find that information.

But those queries are not enough - you have to figure out *all* statements from the involved transactions. This information could only be obtained by logging *all* statements, which is typically not an option.

You'll have to go sleuthing in your application code. One idea that can help is to put comments into the queries that indicate what transaction is being processed.